# Very fast flickering screen (Xubuntu on Lenovo Yoga)

Tags: graphics, video, flicker

I installed Xubuntu (i.e. ubuntu light) on a (laptop/tablet) Lenovo Yoga 900S 12ISK with HD Graphics 915 video card. After bios update (to allow for Linux) installation went fine but the login screen (and thereafter) flickers extremely fast (i.e. being unusable); kernel module i915 is up and running. What should I change?

Comment: What is the Xubuntu version?

Comment: I use Xubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).